# Physical Web mDNS android test - advertising beacon app not displayed

Tags: android, web-services, raspberry-pi, mdns, jmdns

I'm trying to replicate [this](https://github.com/google/physical-web/blob/master/documentation/mDNS_Support.md) RaspberryPI example on Android

I created an app for android to advertise a URL using mDNS (jmDNS library), the app works well and I can receive the message on another phone using [ZeroConf Browser app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.melloware.zeroconf&hl=en_GB)

But when I try to receive the same message using [Physical Web app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=physical_web.org.physicalweb&hl=en) nothing happens, the app doesn't find the service.

I believe the problem is in the way I send hostname and txt-records.

This is my code:

```
serviceInfo = ServiceInfo.create(type,
                            "www.google.github.io", 80,
                            "path=/physical-web/");

                    /*A Key value map that can be advertised with the service*/
                    serviceInfo.setText(getDeviceDetailsMap());
                    jmdns.registerService(serviceInfo);
```

can you help me understand what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

See these discussions:
https://github.com/openhab/jmdns/issues/25
https://github.com/google/physical-web/issues/414

In short, I think the issue is because the url is in a text record, rather than in the service name, but the Physical Web may change the required format in the future...mdns support is still developing.